# Node.js Nodemailer Failed to Send Email

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm unable to send an email in Node.js using Nodemailer. I don't know how to debug it simply because I don't understand the reply from the terminal. I think it is a SSL issue, but as you can see, I've set 'secure' as 'true', so I really don't know where should I start to debug it.

Source Code:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var mailOptions = {
  host: "smtp.mail.me.com",
  port: 587,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: "***",
    pass: "***"
  }
};

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(mailOptions);

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

Result from terminal:

```
{ Error: 140736043987904:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:827:
 code: 'ECONNECTION', command: 'CONN' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using your transport details to send an email. More information can be found https://nodemailer.com/about/.

```
let mailOptions = {
    from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>', // sender address
    to: 'bar@example.com, baz@example.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
    html: '<b>Hello world?</b>' // html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
    // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
    console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

    // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>
    // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
});
```

Comment: Tried this. No new output. Just yields the unhelpful: "Error sending email"